# create an object with keys based on an inner key's value

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, lodash

This is something that could likely be solved by using Underscore or Lo-Dash. And using them, I've come close to the solution I want, but not close enough. And I've come close to finding solutions here on stackoverflow, but none quite seem to get at what I'm after. Here's a rendition of the original and then the object as it might be recreated based on an inner key's value.

**Original**

```
{
    "muppets": [
    {
        "number": {
            "value": "one"
        },
        "name": "Fozzie"
    },
    {
        "number": {
            "value": "two"
        },
        "name": "Kermit"
    },
    {
        "number": {
            "value": "one"
        },
        "name": "Rowlf"
    }
    ]
}
```

What's Needed

```
{
"muppets": [
    {
        "one": [
            {
                "number": {
                    "value": "one"
                },
                "name": "Fozzie"
            },
            {
                "number": {
                    "value": "one"
                },
                "name": "Fozzie"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "two": [
            {
                "number": {
                    "value": "two"
                },
                "name": "Kermit"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  If you expect effort to be put into answers, put effort into your question.

Comment: Please post the code that "brought you close". You cannot just tell others "I have this and I want that".

Comment: I didn't think to post the messy attempts. I'll keep this in mind when crafting questions in the future.

Comment: @jodytate: You still can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
obj.muppets = _.map(_.groupBy(obj.muppets, function(m) {
    return m.number.value;
}), function(a, g) {
    var o={}; o[g]=a; return o;
});
```

Notice that the new `muppets` array is not guaranteed to be sorted in any order.